# Eclipse Plugin Development: Listener for change of view of opened document

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, editor, listener

is there a way to listen whether the user changed the opened document?
(Not just open/close it; it should work when the user switches between already opened documents)

Best regards
Frank

Answer (score 1):

My solution for now:

1. Create a StartupHandler which uses the extension point org.eclipse.ui.startup
2. Do an asynchronous call in the StartupHandler (to be sure eclipse is started) via Display.asyncExec() in which I add a new instance of a class which implements IPartListener2 to the active workbench window:

   ```
   public void earlyStartup() {
       PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Workbench.getInstance().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(new SwitchDocumentListener());
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. Create the class which implements IPartListener2:

   public void partActivated(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
         //do something
      }

Now everytime the viewed document changes, the partActivated() method will be called and you can react.

Comment: Part activation is different than changing a document. If you want only the document changes, use the document change listener associated with IDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the "Editors" section in the Platform Plugin Developer guide, and then the IDocument interface which allows you to register a document change listener.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so. Have you looked at `IResourceChangeListener` and `IResourceDeltaVisitor`?

These are in the `org.eclipse.core.resources` package.

Once you implement `IResourceChangeListener` you can register it as a listener by calling:

`ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener`

and passing your instance to this method.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. The ResourceChangeListener observers the change of one resource, I want to listen to switches between opened documents in the text editor...

Comment: Ah I see. When you said "...changed the opened document" I thought you meant modify it.